# How to learn about heavy usage of templates in C++?

Tags: c++

I've always understood templates as something like this:

```
template<typename T>
class A{
    A(T t) {

    }
}
```

That is, it's something that you put a type and it substitutes. However, I've seen code like this:

```
template<template<typename> typename ProtoApi>
class GetProtoApiHelper {
    template<typename, typename = void>
    struct MatchApi {
        inline static constexpr bool Matches = false;
    };
```

What is `template<typename, typename = void>` supposed to mean? What is `typename` alone and how is it even possible to make `typename=void`? And the worst: how am I supposed to understand

```
template<template<typename> typename ProtoApi>
```

Comment: It's to allow for nested templates. And `typename = void` means "if unspecified, use `void`). See default template parameter arguments: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters

Comment: @Dai In this case it is rather used for template metaprogramming. It actually says in the [source code](https://github.com/ambrop72/aipstack/blob/master/src/aipstack/ip/IpStack.h#L191).
Guerlando: Read up on template metaprogramming and SFINAE if you want to understand this kind of code.